# How to auto format code from the command line?

Tags: command-line, vim, text-formatting, source-code

Let's say I have a JavaScript in someRandomFile.js and I want to run a command like:

```
formatMyCode someRandomFile.js
```

Then inside the file it just indent everything in a nice way.

I want to do format PHP or HTML too.  In VIM you can highlight some text and press = and it'll automagically format it (even if it is mixed HTML/PHP/JavaScript).  Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You can try [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) (sudo apt-get install astyle), but maybe it is better to use some IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you like vim **you can invoke its action from the command-line**.

```
echo -e "G=gg\n:wq\n" | vim ./myfile.php
```

**Warning** the above command **will modify your file without prompting**. Do a backup before.
It's possible to find examples integrated with `find` to accomplish the same work on a bunch of files <sup>[[0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592152/3569208)]</sup>.

Looking beyond it's possible to find a lot of utilities build for this, and this number will continue to grow in time; you can search for their updated versions on internet and you can start for example from:

- Artistic Style <sup>[[1](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)]</sup>, **`astyle`**, for **C, C++, C++/CLI, Objective‑C, C# and Java programming languages.**
- **`tidy`** <sup>[[2](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)]</sup> for **Html**
- **IDE solutions** invoked by command line starting from `kate` <sup>[[3](http://kate-editor.org/2013/02/18/new-plugins-to-the-kate-utils-to-python-javascript-django-and-xml/)]</sup> for which there exists just made plug-in; you can built your own indentation scripts <sup>[[4](http://kate-editor.org/2009/10/29/extending-kate-with-scripts/)]</sup> too, continuing with `UniversalIndentGUI` <sup>[[5](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)]</sup>, `eclipse` <sup>[[5](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)]</sup>...

Comment: I was secretly hoping someone would give a vim example! thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Just a suggestion, next time try to ask it directly, it can be even faster! (In general try to avoid problems similar to the  [xy one](http://xyproblem.info/), it can simplify your and the other's life ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

```
vim -c "execute 'normal! =G' | :wq! out.js" input.js
```

You can also use the alternative syntax `+` instead of `-c`. It's the same.

```
vim +"execute 'normal! =G' | :wq! out.js" input.js
```

1. It executes the normal command `=G`, which will autoformat/indent (`=`) every line until the end of the file (`G`).
2. Then `:wq! out.js` writes it to a file and quits vim. If you just want to overwrite the same file, then remove the `out.js`.

Also, you need to have this line in your `~/.vimrc` in order for the autoformat indent plugin to work:

`filetype plugin indent on`

Answer (score 1):

With eslint, you can

```
eslint --fix someRandomFile.js
```

Also works with JSON files. For HTML, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191989/a-command-line-html-pretty-printer-making-messy-html-readable.